# RDP file with embedded password asks for password

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access, rdp, remote

I've created one RDP file

```
full address:s:10.20.30.40
username:s:myuser
password:s:mypassword
domain:s:mydomain
```

When I open this file it still asks me for the password. What can I do to tell RDP client to use password mentioned in the file instead of asking user?

Answer (score 34):

I had the issue on Windows 10 with perma asking password when I try to connect to a new machine.

First, the password line in the RDP must be named:

```
password 51:b:myEncryptedPassword
```

And the pass must by encrypted. You can use cryptRDP5 to convert it: https://github.com/jps-networks-modifiedOSS/openvpn-als-applications/tree/master/adito-application-rdp-xplatform-embedded/src/windows

```
cryptRDP5.exe yourpassword
```

Note that the generated password is only valid for the machine that did it.

Note 2: cryptRDP5 don't seems to parse correctly a password containing an apostrophe character '
Better to use Powershell as suggested in comments.

Comment: I found that Powershell's `ConvertFrom-SecureString` also works instead of needing that `cryptRDP5.exe`

Comment: For reference, the full powershell command to encrypt a password using the above would be `("MySuperSecretPassword!" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force) | ConvertFrom-SecureString;`

Comment: Is there a linux/osx equivalent of `cryptRDP5.exe`?

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 Note that it doesn't fully match rdp encryption which pads the password with zero bytes to be 512 bytes before encryption.

Comment: `cryptRDP5.exe MySuperSecretPassword` gives a different result from the example in the second comment. In particular, the result from cryptRDP5.exe works, and the one from `ConvertFrom-SecureString` doesn't. Why is that?

Comment: Windows 11 22H2: cryptRDP5 is working, but the powershell command is not working.

Comment: Is there any way to generated password that becomes valid on all machines?

Comment: Using `ConvertFrom-SecureString` in Windows 11 worked for me, specifically `Read-Host -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString`

Answer (score 11):

Open the Group Policy editor (**Start > Run > gpedit.msc**) and navigate to **Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Connection Client**

For value **Do not allow passwords to be saved**, check that is set to **Disabled**.

When connecting to a machine in Remote Desktop Connector, expand the Options panel and confirm that **Allow me to save credentials** is checked.

Comment: I've disabled the value as per your suggestion but it still asks for my password.

Comment: This works only in case the password is encrypted/hashed. For plaintext password, it does not work. Is there any other policy which I've to check for this?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding

```
prompt for credentials:i:0
```

Comment: Have tried that but still asks me for my password.

Comment: Check the message that it gives to you. Maybe a GPO is blocking you to login withouth giving creds

Comment: It's not giving any message saying GPO is blocking the login.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me in combination with `username:s:myuser` and `password 51:b:myEncryptedPassword`.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't managed to do this by modifying the .rdp. But a workaround is, to change the settings of the remote desktop connection application. In Preferences -> User Accounts you can add your account + password:

[image]

Comment: That appears to be for MacOS, not Windows.

Comment: I asume that a similiar option might be in windows version of this Microsoft product available, too. The main trick is not to modify the rdp file, but to put it in the Remote Desktop app preferences.

Comment: Windows doesn't have app preferences.

Comment: this worked for me on macos thank you

Answer (score 0):

To enable the setting, the user can enter `promptcredentialonce:i:1` in the RDP file.

If the user wants to disable the setting, then user can enter `promptcredentialonce:i:0` in the RDP file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python 3 program that inserts username/password into RDP file and also creates LNK file for it (to drag to quick launch, for example). It is based on several existing solutions, credits for those goes to their authors.

```python
import sys, os, getpass, subprocess

if (len(sys.argv) != 2):
    print("\nRDPPassword is a Python 3 program that inserts username")
    print("and password into existing RDP file and creates a LNK file")
    print("that can be dragged to taskbar's QuickLaunch area.")
    print("\nUSAGE: python %s <RDP file>\n" % os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))
    exit(1)

def InsertPassword(rdpfile, user, password):
    fileIn = open(rdpfile, "r", encoding="'utf_16_le")
    lines = fileIn.read().splitlines()
    fileIn.close()
    outLines = []
    bPromptCredentials = False
    bUsername = False
    bPassword = False
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('promptcredentialonce:i:'):
            outLines.append('promptcredentialonce:i:1')
            bPromptCredentials = True
        elif line.startswith('username:s:'):
            outLines.append('username:s:%s' % user)
            bUsername = True
        elif line.startswith('password 51:b:'):
            outLines.append('password 51:b:%s' % password)
            bPassword = True
        elif len(line)>0:
            outLines.append(line)
    if not bPromptCredentials:
        outLines.append('promptcredentialonce:i:1')
    if not bUsername:
            outLines.append('username:s:%s' % user)
    if not bPassword:
            outLines.append('password 51:b:%s' % password)
    
    fileOut = open(rdpfile, "w", encoding="utf_16_le")
    for line in outLines:
        #fileOut.write("%s%s" % (line, os.linesep))
        fileOut.write("%s%s" % (line, '\n'))
        #print("#%s#"%line)
    fileOut.close()

def RunShell(command):
    # pipes usage taken from: https://superuser.com/questions/1540516/how-do-i-execute-powershell-commands-with-pipes-in-python
    PSEXE = r'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
    PSRUNCMD = "Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock "
    process = subprocess.run([PSEXE, PSRUNCMD + "{" + command + "}"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines = True)
    #print("CMD", command)
    #print("ERR", process.stderr)
    #print("OUT", process.stdout)
    return process.stdout

if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
    print("\nFile '%s' not found.\n" % sys.argv[1])
    exit(1)

if not ( (sys.argv[1].endswith(".rdp")) or (sys.argv[1].endswith(".RDP")) ):
    print("\nFile '%s' not a RDP file.\n" % sys.argv[1])
    exit(1)

print("\nInserting username/password into '%s'" % sys.argv[1])
username = input("Username: ")
#password = getpass.getpass("Password: ") #use this if you do not want the password to be seen while typing
password = input("Password: ")

# insert username/password into RDP file
# **************************************
# RDP password generation taken from: https://serverfault.com/questions/867467/rdp-file-with-embedded-password-asks-for-password
PassCmd = "('%s' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force) | ConvertFrom-SecureString;" % password
password = RunShell(PassCmd)

InsertPassword(sys.argv[1], username, password)

# create a LNK file for RDP
# *************************
print("\nCreating a LNK file for '%s'" % sys.argv[1])
# https://superuser.com/questions/298974/how-do-i-pin-a-remote-desktop-connection-to-the-taskbar
RunRdp = r'"%windir%\system32\mstsc.exe"'
RunArgs = "'\"%s\"'" % os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
# https://superuser.com/questions/392061/how-to-make-a-shortcut-from-cmd
LnkCmd = '$ws = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell; $s = $ws.CreateShortcut("%s"); $S.TargetPath = %s; $S.Arguments = %s; $S.Save()' % (sys.argv[1][:-3]+"lnk", RunRdp, RunArgs)
RunShell(LnkCmd)

print("\nDone.\n")
```